# 'Parsing error: Unexpected token' error for an arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, express, parsing

I'm trying to create a web app taking data from a mysql server via Express. The variable cases is the data I receive from the server. When I run the app, 'Parsing error: Unexpected token' at this line `let filtered = cases.filter(case => case.deaths === 0);`. How can I fix this?

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cases: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/cases")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(cases => this.setState({ cases }));
  }

  getUSTotalCases = () => {

    let filtered = cases.filter(case => case.deaths === 0);
    let sum = 0;
    filtered.map(case => sum + case.confirmed);
    return sum;
  };

  render() {
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.state.cases.filter`?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with `filtered.map`.  Try something like this

```
filtered.forEach(case => {
  sum += case.confirmed
)};
```

This will add `case.confirmed` to the previous sum, which I assume is what you expect.

Also, instead of `cases.filter`, you need to reference the state (`this.state.cases.filter`)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions are an es6 feature, so they need to be transpiled to es5.

You can either write non-arrow functions, or you can setup [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions) to transpile your arrow functions.